# Conditional compilation based on Excel version

Tags: excel, vba, compilation, excel-2010, excel-2013

I know that I can use conditional compilation in VBA to differentiate between the 64bit and the 32bit version (using `#If VBA7 Then ...`).

Is there also a build in constant similar to `Application.Version` so that I can differentiate between Excel 2013/2010/2007/... etc. at compile time?

Also, is there a list of available existing compiler constants? So far I found `VBA7` and `Win64` (e.g. from [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Bitness.aspx) article) - but are there any other ones?

Comment: I'm unaware of any built in constants - the standard method is to use `Val(Application.Version)`

Comment: Pity that it cant be broken down at compile time. but I guess that's just the way it is...

Comment: The VBA7 constant doesn't tell you if you're using a 64-bit application.  It tells you if you're using at least VBA7 (which could be a 32-bit or 64-bit application).  The Win64 constant tells you if you're using a 64-bit application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/compiler-constants), you have the following constants:

```
VBA6
VBA7
Win64
Win32
Win16
Mac
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to the version granularity questioned, but I had a need to separate Office 365/XL16- specific code from its predecessors. VBA7 is backwards compatible with VBA6, and VBA6 knows nothing of VBA7. We can use this to our advantage.

```
Sub testit()
#If VBA6 And VBA7 Then
   Debug.Print "Cool!" 'XL16 vba code
#Else
   Debug.Print "Yeah!" 'Not XL16 vba code
#End If
End Sub
```

XL14 and below evaluate #If as if true/false, XL16 as true/true. If it's just #If VBA7, XL14 attempts to compile the XL16 code. I don't know why, but that's how it tested.